# IPython (Jupyter) cell magics and cross-language interaction

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic, cross-language

In a normal ipython notebook or repl session, I can refer to previously-run cells using the _# notation.

However, this is not possible when using cell magics such as %%perl or %%bash because these cells do not have entries in _oh. Nor can I find a way for any two languages to refer to values in the other's namespace.

Does anyone know a way to move information between cells that use different languages, other than using an external file?

Comment: They should still be in the input history; you're right that their output is not part of the output history.

Comment: You're right, and I removed the reference to _ih. It was immaterial to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a method that involves using multiple cell magics.

```
%%capture perl_out
%%perl
```

will create a CapturedIO object and allow `str(perl_out)` to be used in a python cell. A fuller example is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/reikoNeko/67f653c175436a2c15f921ea6853e4da).